# how to tell nav bar user just logged in or sign out in angular 2 and bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar that has buttons on it like user profile and other "after login" components.
now, after i sign in or log out i would like to tell the component which own the nav bar that the user is no longer valid or the opposite to the component that the user is just logged in so display the elements on the navbar

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide any code? You will get a much better responsive if you can do both of those things.

Comment: @A1raa I answered to my question and it would be wondeful if you can comment on it and let me know what do you think...

Answer (score 3):

I tool this idea from the official angular 2 [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)  that demonstrate comunication between parent and child. though its not a parent and child i think it good approach and its work perfectly for me. ok, so we need to create a service for this that can help up communicate between the login component ( and register component ) and the navigation bar component.
i called it:LocalStorageService because i store the user object in the local storage.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private logoutAnnoucedSource = new Subject<string>();

  loginAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  logoutAnnounced$ = this.logoutAnnoucedSource.asObservable();

  announceLogin(mission: string) {
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
  }    

  announceLogout(){
    this.logoutAnnoucedSource.next(null);
  }
}
```

great, now we just need to announce login or log out to the navbar component inside the login or register component:

```
import { Component, OnInit }                   from '@angular/core';
import { Router }                              from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/localStorage.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;

    constructor(
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) 
        { }

    login() {
        this.announce();   
        this.router.navigate(['/UserProfile']);              
    }


    announce() {
         let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
          if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
              return this.localStorageService.announceLogin(currentUser); 
          }      
    }
}
```

good, now in the navbar component which i called app.component we need to "listen" to those announcements:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from './services/localStorage.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent { 
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {

        this.subscription = localStorageService.loginAnnounced$.subscribe(
            currentUser => {
            this.currentUser = currentUser;
        });

        this.subscription = localStorageService.logoutAnnounced$.subscribe(
            empty => {
            this.currentUser = null;
       });
       //when the app refresh or initialized
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    }
}
```

now this is the app.component.html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button *ngIf="currentUser" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Brand" src="app/images/syte_logo.png"></a>
        </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
      <ul *ngIf="currentUser" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li *ngIf="currentUser" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink] = "['/Analytics']" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Analytics</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="currentUser" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink] = "['/Integration']" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Integration</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="currentUser" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink] = "['/FAQ']" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="currentUser" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink] = "['/Terms']" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Terms</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="currentUser" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink] = "['/Contact']" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li *ngIf="currentUser" routerLinkActive="active">
               <a [routerLink] = "['/UserProfile']" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
               Hi, {{currentUser.name}}
             </a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div> <!--collapse-->
   </div>
  </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="starter-template">
          <alert-custom></alert-custom>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if you have better solution i will be glad to hear about it

Comment: Use Behaviour Subect